# msn plus script read/write memory

Tags: javascript, interop, msn

I'm writing on a MSN Plus script, which is in fact javascript.
For interop with Windows there is a class called `Interop`.
With its static function `Call` one can call s specified function in a specified dll with up to 12 arguments.
My goal is to write a script which gets a process name out of the PID.
I've done everything right, but it still doesn't work.

```
function GetProcNameFromPID(pid)  
{
    var hnd = Interop.Call("kernel32", "CreateToolhelp32Snapshot", 2, 0);
    var handle = Interop.Call("kernel32", "GetCurrentProcess");
    var StructP = Interop.Allocate(4+4+4+4+4+4+4+4+4+260);//*Allocate space for the ProcessEntry32 struct*
    var hnd_ptr = Interop.Allocate(4);
    var ress = Interop.Call("kernel32", "WriteProcessMemory", handle, StructP, StructP.size.DataPtr, 4, hnd_ptr);
    Debug.Trace(ReadInt(hnd_ptr, 0));
    var res = Interop.Call("kernel32", "Process32FirstW", hnd, StructP.DataPtr);
    if(!res)
    {
        Debug.Trace("FAAAAIIIILLLLL / " + Interop.Call("kernel32", "GetLastError") + " / " + ress);
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            var pos = 0;
            ReadInt(StructP, pos);
            ReadInt(StructP, pos);
            var owpid = ReadInt(StructP, pos);
            ReadInt(StructP, pos);
            ReadInt(StructP, pos);
            ReadInt(StructP, pos);
            var parpid = ReadInt(StructP, pos);
            ReadInt(StructP, pos);
            ReadInt(StructP, pos);
            ReadInt(StructP, pos);
            var name = ReadString(pos, 50);
            if(pid == owpid)
                return name;
            StructP = Interop.Allocate(4+4+4+4+4+4+4+8+4+50);
            Interop.Call("kernel32", "WriteProcessMemory", handle, StructP.DataPtr, StructP.size.DataPtr, 4, null);
        }
            while(Interop.Call("kernel32", "Process32NextW", hnd, StructP.DataPtr) == true)
    }
}
function ReadInt(buffer, pos)
{
var res = 0; 
    for(var i = 0; i >> 24;  
    var b2 = addr >> 24;  
    var b3 = addr >> 24;  
    var b4 = addr >> 24;  
    return b4 + b3*256 + b2*256*256 + b1*256*256*256;  
}
```

---

The `Process32FirstW` function always  suceeds, but the struct is empty.
The `WriteProcessMemory` function suceeds, too. But the number of written bytes is always 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a machine to test things on, but your first issue is you don't appear to be passing [the proper parameters to `WriteProcessMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681674%28VS.85%29.aspx):

```
BOOL WINAPI WriteProcessMemory(
  __in   HANDLE hProcess,
  __in   LPVOID lpBaseAddress,
  __in   LPCVOID lpBuffer,
  __in   SIZE_T nSize,
  __out  SIZE_T *lpNumberOfBytesWritten
);
```

You're passing...

```
handle => hProcess,
StructP => lpBaseAddress, // ???
StructP.size.DataPtr => lpBuffer, // ???
4 => nSize,
hnd_ptr => lpNumberOfBytesWritten
```

Let's start with an overview of WriteProcessMemory: It's supposed to take a chunk of data in the curent process, pointed to by lpBuffer, nSize bytes long.  It copies that data into the memory space of the process indicated by hProcess and places that data at the address lpBaseAddress in that target process.

The problems I see with your code are:

1. `lpBaseAddress` should be the address in another process which you are writing to.  Since your `handle` points to the current process, I don't even know why you'd call this function to begin with.  You can just use `StructP.WriteWORD(Offset, Data)` to write data to your structure.  But I'll presume for now you're doing this for bare minimum demonstraction purposes — to see if you can get `WriteProcessMemory()` to work at all.
2. I don't think this is even valid code.  [`StructP.size` exists, but it's an int, not an object](http://mpscripts.net/docs/ref-databloc-size.php).  It has no DataPtr member.  `StructP.DataPtr` also exists.  In fact, [`StructP.DataPtr` is what is sent if you just specify `StructP` according to the help file](http://mpscripts.net/docs/ref-interop-call.php).  So are you trying to write *from* the structure right back *to* the structure, again, as a minimum test?  If so, both pointers should be `StructP`

Following that, I don't know where the `ReadInt()` function you are using comes from.  It looks to me like Databloc has several member functions for reading values, but you would call them like: `hnd_ptr.ReadWORD(0)`

I am unsurprised that the structure is empty after calling `Process32FirstW()`, as [it checks the value of the `dwSize` member of the structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684834%28VS.85%29.aspx).  Since you are not successfully writing to it, I expect that value is normally 0, and hence no data is written.

I've never fiddled with Messger Plus, so you'll have to forgive me a little for being befuddled by a lot of this. Let me know if any of this was useful.

Comment: Well I'm trying to do a PID to Process Name script in combination with other scripts it can be quite useful. For now I have delted the WriteProcessMemory() function and tried with StuctP.WriteDWORD(0,296); and then Interop.Call("kernel32", "Process32FirstW", hnd, StructP.DataPtr); but it still fails. I really don't know what else to do.